# Google Map APIs Map Creating Error

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I created fragment in .xml file:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 />
```

and I also init. GoogleMap and fragment objects in .java file:

```
private GoogleMap maps;
private View fragment1;

fragment1 = findViewById(R.id.map);
```

but When I was trying to create GoogleMap object

```
maps = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I'm getting an error on `getFragmentManager()`  eclipse couldn't find this method

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your class extends FragmentActivity and your android project is google api project.

Comment: true answer is here! :)

Answer (score 0):

in Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and in Java File

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  mMap = fm.getMap();
```

follow this tutorial 
[Google Map Using Fragment](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application>

    ...

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="HERE GOES YOUR API KEY" />

</application>
```

Comment: There is no problem on API key and other settings

Comment: @user3138900 Make Sure this Package imported  1)import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;  
 2)import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

Comment: @user3138900 try above updated code added in java file section

Comment: I added two imports  but erro still remain :(

Answer (score 0):

pls import the class , "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity "  Class in your main activity.

it can be imported if u have the google play service downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

> **Check your manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR KEY" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> **Check your layout file:**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

> **Check your source file:**

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: ty but problem is "public class xxx extends FragmentActivity" :)

Answer (score 0):

no need to extend FragmentActivity

**try below code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! unable to create maps",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```